# Can't simulate keyDown (jest+enzyme)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Edit: I ended up using `onChange` to update the value, which has the benefit of mocking entire strings, rather than individual characters.

---

I'm using keydown to discern whether to update input value, or add a todo.

The functionality works when tested in the browser, but when simulated with enzyme, the todo isn't added to the snapshot (as if the simulation never occurs).

```js
it('should add a new todo', () => {
  const component = mount(<TodoList />)
  const Input = component.find('.new-todo-input')
  let wrapper = toJson(component);
  
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
  
  Input.simulate('keydown', { key: 'z', keyCode: 90, which: 90 })
  Input.simulate('keydown', { key: 'Enter', keyCode: 13, which: 13 })
  
  wrapper = toJson(component);
  
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

You can find the rest of [the code here](https://github.com/NirBenita/todo-pomo/blob/test-suite/src/components/Todo.tsx).

Comment: What is the displayed error whenn you run this tesT?

Comment: All the needed info to help you should be provided inside your question. May you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks @AbdennourTOUMI, there's no error... It's just that the simulation doesn't occur

Answer (score 1):

I checked [your code in github](https://github.com/NirBenita/todo-pomo/blob/test-suite/src/components/Todo.tsx#L30) . Because you are using `e.preventDefault()`, you should mock it as well :

```
 Input.simulate('keydown', { preventDefault(){}, key: 'z', keyCode: 90, which: 90 })
```

Comment: Thanks! I added it to my test, but the snapshot still does not contain the new todo